# Infrastructure networks in GIS modelling

Tags: open-source-gis, network, modelling, software-recommendations, infrastructure

I am currently working on a GIS-based project which aims to model the interdependency of existing infrastructure networks, e.g. transport, oil, pipeline networks, etc. The network interdependency include the interactions between networks in terms of physical or  geographical respective. This is quit important as it might lead to cascading effect among these networks.

We would like to develop a modelling platform/software with GIS function so the advantages of geographical relationships can be fully explored. We have already started some works based on a few open-source libraries and software. However, I hope I am open-minded, and am wondering if there are any existing software tools/publication related to this aspect?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a **[PostGIS database with topology data type and functions](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/Topology.html)**.

QGIS also has some topology functionality built in - this could be used if you're looking to have a desktop front end to your platform.

Comment: Thank you for this. I actually have used SharpMap as the front-end GIS to display network data and PostGIS/PostgreSQL as database engine to store network data.